# Add a note line below the matrix

Tags: matrices, annotations

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\begin{bmatrix}[cccc]
    1&-1&0&2\\
    0&1&-4&-2\\
    0&0&1&\frac{3}{5}\\[3pt]
    0&0&0&-\frac{22}{5}
\end{bmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

I want add a note line below matrix like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really like redefining `bmatrix`, but you can, if you prefer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{bmatrix*}[1]
 {%
  \left[%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{@{}#1@{}}
 }
 {\endarray\right]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\underset{\text{(row-echelon form)}}{%
  \begin{bmatrix*}{ccc|c}
    1&-1&0&2\\
    0&1&-4&-2\\
    0&0&1&\frac{3}{5}\\[3pt]
    0&0&0&-\frac{22}{5}
  \end{bmatrix*}%
 }$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
${\begin{bmatrix}[cccc]
    1&-1&0&2\\
    0&1&-4&-2\\
    0&0&1&\frac{3}{5}\\[3pt]
    0&0&0&-\frac{22}{5}
\end{bmatrix} \atop \text{\normalsize(row-echelon form)}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank sir, it worked.

Comment: Here there is an unwritten rule. Never use Thanks and Sorry. But if the solution works, upvote the answer and do not forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution using the package `spalign`. Into there are differents commands to increase the space between the rows and the vertical line like your image. The alignment it is to the right `r`. See `\spalignaugmatn[r]`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{spalign}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1} 
\begin{document}
\[\spaligndelims{[}{]}\underset{\textup{(row-echelon form)}}{\spalignaugmatn[r]{1}{1 -1 0 2; 0 1 -4 -2; 0 0 1 \frac{3}{5}; 0 0 0 -\frac{22}{5}}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]